# Show that $\vec x \cdot \vec y \leq ||\vec x||$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, vectors

Suppose $\vec x, \vec y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $||\vec y||=1$. Show that $\vec x \cdot \vec y \leq ||\vec x||$.

From the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality it follows that 
$$\vec x\cdot \vec y \leq |\vec x \cdot \vec y| \leq ||\vec x || \, ||\vec y||=|| \vec x ||$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. this is correct.

Comment: yes, it's correct

Comment: Let me just add that you get the same from $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}=||\vec{x}||\,||\vec{y}||\cos{\theta}$.